# Latex (TeXmaker and MiKTeX) and onedrive conflict

Tags: miktex, texmaker, windows

I have a rather anoying issue with my setup. I have worked with TeXmaker and MiKTeX for years, and all went fine until recently when I have made the switch to onedrive. 
The issue now is that when I want to work on my .tex files, I get the
"Could not start the command
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
which is my path to the pdf latex (defalut texmaker)

HOWEVER, this works perfectly if I move the file out of onedrive (for example onto my desktop). This is a workaround, but it is very annoying. Anybody has an idea?

I run up to date MiKTeX and TeXmaker on Windows 10. The onedrive files are from the file explorer (not the website), and are downloaded on my computer.

Thank you kindly

Comment: can you compile your file from the command line? that is can you run `pdflatex "file.tex"` (on what ever filename you are using).

Comment: Hello, 
Thank you for your answser. When I try to run a .tex file that is on my ondrive form the CMD, I get the error massage " ! I can't write on file 'file.tex'. Changing the settings of onedrive to "always keep on the device" doesn't change this. It seems its just missing an autorisation to write in the onedrive folder....

Comment: That makes no sense at all as `pdflatex` does not write any LaTeX files. Exactly what are you doing? does this `hello.tex` doc work: `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}hello\end{document}` when placed and compiled inside the OneDrive foler.

Comment: So after a bit more investigation I still have no idea what is happening. I the simple document you have suggested, and when I try to save it to onedrive I get a popup saying I do not have permission, contact admin (I am the admin). If I save it on my desktop and then move it to my onedrive, I can open it, it runs fine. However, I can only run it once. If I close it and reopen it, or modify it and recompile, I get the error again.

Comment: SO, I have figured it out. It appears that because of the coronavirus and teleoffice my antivirus provider gave vitamins to the system because of the high increase in malawares etc.  And it was blocking most of the processes that were not "mainline office". So yeah.. sorry for wasting your time... Big thanks though !